# Does the viasat 3 that will be launching today have expendable side booster

Tags: reuse, falcon-heavy

The reuse of space system is the requirement of the future. Today A falcon heavy is launched for viasat-3. Is launch profile of the rocket fully expendable or partially expendable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [NASASpaceFlight](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2023/04/viasat-3-americas/):

> The Falcon Heavy for this mission — consisting of core B1068, booster B1052, and booster B1053 — will be expended due to the need for all available performance. This results from needing to insert the ViaSat-3 Americas satellite directly into geostationary orbit.

Though as noted in the article, the side boosters have already been used in a previous Falcon Heavy launch, and one booster has been used repeatedly as a Falcon 9 booster. In this case, they’re expending the boosters to maximize satellite lifetime instead of expending the satellite’s fuel to get it to its final orbit.

Comment: Falcon Heavy launches rarely enough that they can afford to build new center cores, and Falcon 9 launches often enough that they always have some high-lifetime boosters to throw away. Perfect fit.